# How can 2 independent variables lead to a single variable parametrization? (Intuition)

Tags: linear-algebra, intuition, interpolation, geometric-interpretation

Take the following formula:
$$
\mu_{ij}=\left(\alpha_i\Sigma_i^{-1}+\alpha_j\Sigma_j^{-1}\right)^{-1}
\left(\alpha_i\Sigma_i^{-1}\mu_i+\alpha_j\Sigma_j^{-1}\mu_j\right).
$$

Where the alphas are scalars, the sigmas are invertible matrices and the mus are vectors.

By defining:

$$
t = \frac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_i + \alpha_j}
$$

And $s = \alpha_i + \alpha_j$

We can establish that $\alpha_i = st$ and $\alpha_j = (1-t)s$.

Using the above fact we can turn the first formula into:

$$
\mu_{ij}=\left(t\Sigma_i^{-1}+(1-t)\Sigma_j^{-1}\right)^{-1}
\left(t\Sigma_i^{-1}\mu_i+(1-t)\Sigma_j^{-1}\mu_j\right).
$$

What's important here is that both formulas are equal to each other. However, assuming that the only restrictions imposed on the variables are that $\alpha_i, \alpha_j >= 0$ and that $\alpha_i + \alpha_j$ > 0.

I find this result "impossible". The first equation has 2 independent variables, the value of $\alpha_i$ has nothing to do with the value of $\alpha_j$. This, in my head is a "2D manifold", it should be locally homeomorphic to the 2D plane.

The second equation however looks like a 1D manifold.

In other words, what makes me very confused here is, somehow the above formula seems to make 2 independent variables vary together such that they behave indistinguishably from a single variable. And I find this result very counter intuitive.

I hope the above conveys what I find confusing about this problem. And hopefully someone can enlighten me about it. I believe the result because the algebra doesn't lie, I am looking for a way to understand what's going on intuitively or visually.

A thing I just realized that is helping a bit is:

Consider $f(t) = t^2$ this is a 1D manifold, i.e it's one dimensional.

I can, if I want, define $t = x + y$ so $f(t) = (x + y)^2$. The result is a 2D manifold. However it's not that both formulas represent the same surface, the functions are different. The result is the same but the functions are different. One function is a set of ordered pairs where both values are scalars and the other is a set of order pairs where the input is a vector and the output is a scalar, i.e the 2 formulas above are NOT the same function, that's why one is a 2D manifold and the other is a 1D manifold.

Is that a correct way to think about it?

Comment: You simply showed that the value of your expression depends only on the ratio between $\alpha_i$ and $\alpha_j$, i.e. if you multiply both by the same constant then the value won't change. That is completely fine and indeed true. Consider for instance the function $f(\alpha_i,\alpha_j)=\alpha_i\alpha_j^{-1}$. It has the same property, but would you still call it counter-intuitive?

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Yes actually, for the same reasons. I am having trouble wrapping my head around the idea that 2 independent variables can be combined to create a single independent variable.

Comment: Your idea that a "function is a manifold" unnecessarily confuses you. There can be a relation, but not as direct as "number of variables" = "dimension of some (what?) manifold". Even more extremely consider $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0$. Would you say that $n$ independent variables were combined into 0 variables?

Comment: It just so happens that for some functions the dimension of the image is smaller than the dimension of the domain (in whatever sense of the word dimension). Nothing wrong about that.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek the function you provided in your example is just the n hyperplane centered at the origin of the n+1 space.

e.g if n=2, and $x=x_1$ and $y=x_2$, then $f(x_1, x_2) = 0$ is a representation of the xy plane, (the z coordinate being the result of the function).

It's not the dimension of the image that I am getting my confusion from, rather it's the dimension of the domain. In one representation the domain is 2D and in another it is 1D. That's what seems to be throwing me off.